# What are the differences in G Suite's Gmail/Google Chat between "Start group conversation" and "Create room"?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, google-chat

What are the differences between these two choices in G Suite Gmail's Interface?

[image: Group conversation vs room]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Gmail calls it "Conversations" in the UI (at least in Gmail), but "Group Messages" in support.

Once acknowledging this limitation, the answer is in
[About rooms and group messages](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/7659784), which states:

1. Conversations are basically 100% identical to a regular chats except having more than 2 participants.
2. Rooms offer features such as:

   1. Setting a room's name
   2. Entrance moderation
   3. @mentions
   4. Assigning tasks
   5. viewing shared files